# How to validate html during pull request?

Tags: html, github, w3c-validation

Is it possible to validate all indicated files during pull request? I used to use Travis CI and I am looking for same type of plugin but for validation not for tests, for example W3C validation or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/svenkreiss/html5validator

There is a plugin to a Travis CI that validate your html. I used it and it works!